# Disk space full not changing after mount folder on other disk

Tags: mount, fstab

I have a Virtual Machine setup on azure.
I see basic disk was getting full so I attached disk to it and mounted `/home/user/mydata` folder to the new disk.
I forgot to add configuration in fstab.
My VM got restarted recently and after restart I did manual mount but disk is not freeing after mount command.

```
/dev/sda1        29G   28G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.4G  8.0K  3.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           697M  396K  697M   1% /run
none            5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
none             64K     0   64K   0% /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d
overflow        1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
/dev/sdb1       281G   63M  267G   1% /mnt
/dev/sdc1      1007G  118G  838G  13% /home/user/mydata
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new mountpoint is shadowing the old path, making it invisible, but still present on disk. What you need to do is unmount /home/user/mydata:

```
sudo umount /home/user/mydata
```

mount it on another path:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 </mnt/somewhere>
```

move whatever data you need from /home/user/mydata to the temporarily mounted path.

Then delete the remaining files:

```
rm -fr /home/user/mydata/*
```

Verify that the space is freed, then remount:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: Its my production server so deleting a folder seems to be bit risky for me. What should I do.

Comment: On umount when i do df -h shows /dev/sda1 100%

Comment: Yes, it's expected to, until you remove the data. If you want to, archive it to another drive, before deleting it. That way you can always recover.

Comment: Great! It's funny little caveat of the Unix Filesystem Hierarchy Standard.

Comment: @AndersOlsson Instead of recommending to delete the data in home, please [edit] your answer and advise to mount the second partition somewhere else (e.g. `/mnt`), then move all data from the source location in home to the mounted partition, then unmount it again and mount it to the real target mountpoint. That way you preserve all the data.

Comment: Good suggestion, @ByteCommander!