# Please can someone help? File system keeps filling up, no idea why?

Tags: docker

hopefully someone here can help me. My file system keeps filling up. 64 Gib in 5 days!!!

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04.02 LTS as a VM on proxmox.

All i have install on ubuntu is docker with various images (portainer, surfshark, qBittorrent, ombi, radarr, sonarr and prowlarr). I also have a CIFS share mounted in /media/ directory which qBittorrent is downloading files to.

When i run 'df -h' it shows '/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv' use as being 100%. Then if i run 'du' or 'ncdu' it shows no large directories/files taking up my storage except for /var/lib/docker/* which is 14GiB.

'/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv' is curently at 64 GiB and i've had to enlarge it temporarily so the sytem still runs but the usage keeps increasing. What could be causing this? I feel like it must be docker for some reason but in reality i have no idea. ncdu doesnt show docker as being 64 GiB or even close to it.

Something else to note (may be irelevant). I have connected qBittorrent to the CIFS share in the docker compose like this:

volumes:
- /media/share/downloads:/downloads

I noticed earlier that qBittorrent started downloading files even though my CIFS was unmounted. No idea where it saved the files but it has stored them somewhere localy as disk space has increased and restarting the docker container oncec CIFS was mounted made no difference to local storage usage.

Can anyone help me? I have purged docker already and it made no difference.

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu 20.04.2 then you're very behind on security fixes & normal fixes too etc...   A fully upgraded system will report as [20.04.6](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2023-March/000287.html), and with [20.04.3](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/) being back in August 2021 your system is very behind on fixes esp. in relation to security.  I suggest maintaining your system better.   (*Note:  the release dates are for ISO release, installed systems upgraded prior to the dates listed*)

Comment: If you downloaded files to a mountpoint while the remote filesystem was unmounted, then they may be hidden under the current mounted filesystem - unmount it again and check

Comment: ... see related [Disk space full not changing after mount folder on other disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727196/disk-space-full-not-changing-after-mount-folder-on-other-disk) and [2nd drive fills up storage space on root file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161881/2nd-drive-fills-up-storage-space-on-root-file-system)